# Loading Svgs with file-loader Web pack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, styled-components, webpack-file-loader

In my webpack configuration, I have

```
 {
    test: /\.(woff|ttf|otf|eot|woff2|png|svg)$/i,
    loader: 'file-loader',
 }
```

which correctly reads the file and produced a hash when I attempt to import the file (this is the console.log of the import)

```
8c0ac5df695d44661b940bfba0814236.svg
```

Now the problem is when I pass this url to a styled component, it doesn't display it.
Here is my folder structure

```
src
  components
       component1
           index
           styled
  icons
    svg
     send.svg
```

I import the svg file from the index like this (all imports are relative to the src)

```
import send from 'icons/svg/send.svg';
```

and then use a styled component which accepts the URL:

```
export const FooterButton = styled.div`
       mask: url(${props => props.icon}) ;
       -webkit-mask-size: contain;
   `;
```

Comment: Did you use the alias feature before? because I see that you have used the icons folder into nested folders without writing the icons relative path.

Comment: No,i haven't used it before.Can you explain further?

Comment: Clear informations are documented here: [official webpack document](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias)

Comment: Oh wait you are talking about importing the send from inside the component? If so,then yes I have and it is imported correctly

Comment: The first and foremost things you need to know is you can't pass the SVG generated file string to a component because that will change after a new rebuild or starting the project. You should use that path directly into an image tag or load as a component.